# Redirect to canonical URL is not working

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm trying to set the canonical URL for my site (macton.com) to add the www in the beginning. The site is hosted using IIS and I installed the URL Rewriter Extension.

Here is the code I put in the web.config file. However, it doesn't seem to do anything, because it remains macton.com.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rewrite to www" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^macton\.com$" />
                </conditions>

                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.macton.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

After this I have a bunch of <location> tags with redirects that work fine. I tried using a redirect from macton.com → www.macton.com but that just creates an infinite redirect loop (DUH!)

Any idea why this wouldn't be working? Everywhere I look says this is the correct code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link can help:
http://www.awseibert.net/how-to/redirecting-canonical-names-in-iis-7

Have you also added macton.com to the binding of your website?